# Can an IAM user give permissions to another user on a resource he does not own?

Tags: amazon-iam

If IAMuser1 creates an s3 bucket he is the owner of the bucket. If IAMuser2 creates another IAMUser3, can he attach an identity based policy to IAMuser3 giving access to the s3 bucket created by IAMuser1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: Can an IAM user give permissions to another user on a resource he does not own?

A: Yes. IAM user does not own the resource. It's the root AWS account to which the IAM user belongs own the resource.

> Q: If `IAMuser1` creates an S3 bucket, he is the owner of the bucket.

> A: The "owner" of a bucket or an object in a bucket is not an individual IAM user, but rather the AWS account to which that user belongs.
>
> Reference: https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate/discussion/-KPST25Z-1SVLVN7bfDW/owner-of-a-s3-bucket-file-in-s3-bucket?answer=-LEqBetBhyq9dAYn7wu9

> Q: If `IAMuser2` creates another `IAMUser3`, can he (`IAMuser2`) attach an identity based policy to `IAMuser3` giving access to the S3 bucket created by `IAMuser1`?

A: It depends on what IAM permissions the `IAMuser2` has. In order to give `IAMuser3` access to the S3 bucket created by `IAMuser1`, `IAMuser2` needs `PutUserPolicy` or `AttachUserPolicy` on the `IAMuser3` IAM user resource.